# HoloLens error: "There were deployment errors. Continue?"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to deploy an application I built in Unity to the HoloLens 2 by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02?tabs=winxr) tutorial.

Here are the build settings I entered in Unity.
[image: Build settings in Unity]

When I go to deploy the application by selecting "Master", "ARM64", "Device" and then "Start without debugging" in Visual Studio I get this error "There were deployment errors. Continue?". If I select yes then I get the below error:

```
Error DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication. 
Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings.
COMException - Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
[0x80004005] XamlControlsGallery
```

I have the Microsoft HoloLens portal open and logged in to the HoloLens, both the laptop and HoloLens are on the same WiFi.

I've tried:

- Restarting Visual Studio, Microsoft HoloLens portal, the HoloLens, my laptop.
- Rebuilding the project from Unity.
- Using all combinations of "Release" or "Master" and "ARM64" or "x64" and "Device".

Comment: HoloLens 1 is x86 .. HoloLens 2 is Arm64 .. Which one are you using and is your device connected via USB?

Comment: I'm using HoloLens 2 (updated question)—sorry should've mentioned this. The device is not connected via USB but is connected via the device portal.

Comment: Have you tried not using `127.0.0.1` (which is your PC itself) but rather the correct IP your HoloLens2 has? If you have trouble to find it turn it on and say "What is my IP" then the HoloLens2 will display it's IP

Comment: @derHugo I did but then I just get the same error message but with the devices IP address.

Comment: Please refer to the 'important' note at the bottom of the page, is your HoloLens 2 in Developer Mode and paired with the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work by following these steps:

1. Make sure the build settings in Unity are the same as the settings you will use in Visual Studio except that the device setting should be "Local machine".
2. In Visual Studio, select "Remote Machine".
3. After opening the project in Visual Studio, select Edit > Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging and enter the IP address for the device.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy to HoloLens over Wi-Fi, please select "Remote Machine" instead of "Device" in the deployment target drop-down menu. And then, go to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging, and enter the IP address of your device in the Address or Machine Name field, more information please see: [Deploying a HoloLens app over Wi-Fi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#deploying-a-hololens-app-over-wi-fi)

Comment: I did this but then I still get "There were deployment errors. Continue?" error. 

However, if I click continue, then I get an alert saying "BookstraForDebugging returned null instead of IPAddress & PortNumber of the remote msvsmon process".

I've also updated the question with the build settings from Unity.

Comment: In the Unity Build Setting step, set "Build and Run on" property as "Local Machine". Your settings should be the same as the image in this document:[1. Build the Unity project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02?tabs=winxr#1-build-the-unity-project)

Comment: The settings described by @Hernando - MSFT are intended for Visual Studio and not for Unity. You should switch back to 'local machine' in Unity and set the above settings in the Visual Studio Solution and try again.

Comment: For the setting on Visual Studio, please follow my answer to select "Remote Machine". If the issue still occurs for you, please provide more Screenshots of your VS Setting.